# Get count of not matching records mysql laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to get the count of the not matching records from two tables.

One table has records with leading 0(i.e 0199) and other have the integer values.(i.e 199)

```
DB::table('booking')
    ->whereRaw('booking_pdf.bid != booking.id')
    ->leftjoin('booking_pdf', 'booking.id', '=', 'booking_pdf.bid')
    ->count();
```

But didn't get the result.
Also tried like this,

```
$bookList = DB::table('booking_pdf')->groupBy('bid')->pluck('bid');
DB::table('booking')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $bookList)
    ->count();
```

But because of leading 0 records, I'm not getting the proper count.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: _“Where am I wrong?”_ - in having those leading zeroes be part of the values in the first place …?

Comment: @CBroe it is the part of the values and want to compare the values without leading zeros.

Comment: _“it is the part of the value”_ - yes, but _why_? This sounds like a pure formatting issue, so this should only be applied when you _output_ the data.

Comment: @CBroe Okay mate. Thanks. Changed the column datatype to the integer.